# «Экономический, офицерский, сочетание». Все слова с безударной непроверяемой гласной?

Tags: егэ

Я делал задание под номером 9 из ЕГЭ по русскому языку. В задании предложено несколько рядов слов, среди которых нужно найти такие ряды, в которых во всех словах содержится безударная непроверяемая гласная корня. Вопрос у меня вызывает только один ряд - ***экономический, офицерский, сочетание.***

В слове ***экономИческий*** я выделил корень ***эконом***. В корне есть три безударные гласные. Проверить смог только одну гласную - **вторую** букву **О** (*эконОмика*). Я думаю, что остальные гласные являются непроверяемыми, поэтому слово *экономический* удовлетворяет условию задания.

В слове ***офицЕрский*** я выделил корень ***офицЕр***. В корне есть две безударные гласные - **О** и **И**. Проверить эти гласные у меня не получилось, поэтому я решил, что это слово также удовлетворяет условию задания.

В слове ***сочетАние*** я выделил корень ***сочетА***. В корне есть две безударные гласные - **О** и **Е**. Я думаю, что постановку буквы **Е** можно объяснить чередованием гласных, но букву **О** проверить я не смог и решил, что это слово также удовлетворяет условию задания.

Я пришел к выводу, что все слова этого ряда имеют безударную непроверяемую гласную в корне, но номера этого ряда нет в ответе к заданию. Выходит, что я где-то ошибся, а в ряду есть слово, которое не содержит безударную непроверяемую гласную в корне. Пожалуйста, подскажите, где я рассуждаю неверно?

Comment: Ссылку можете дать на источник этого ЕГЭ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я постараюсь найти электронную версию сборника вариантов, из которого я взял это задание. Не сказал бы, что сборник сомнительного происхождния. Он создавался под редакцией И. П. Цыбулько, и его рекомендует ФИПИ. Если не найду электронную версию, придется прикрепить фотографии задания и ответа

Comment: А, то есть это официально изданный сборник? И официальные ответы к нему? Ну тогда другое дело, просто тут часто вопросы из непонятных источников встречаются. Впрочем, на суть проблемы (расхождения с Тихоновым) это никак не влияет.

Comment: *Если не найду электронную версию, придется прикрепить фотографии задания и ответа* - в данном случае это излишне, коли вы дали какие-то выходные данные бумажной книги. Фотографии нужны, когда есть какие-то разночтения самого первоисточника. а тут-то все понятно.

Comment: Да, это официально изданный сборник, ответы к заданиям я смотрю в конце самого сборника. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В слове сочетАние я выделил корень сочетА

Вот тут явно повод для недоразумений.

Вы, видимо, воспользовались рекомендованным "школьным" словарем Тихонова, который дает разложение по мофемам как ***сочета'/ни/е [й/э]***. Не знаю, чем он руководствовался (возможно, связал с глаголом "сочетать", от которого  отбросил формообразующий суффикс "-ть"), но на самом деле таких корней не бывает. *За исключением единичных древнейших корней, истинный, исторический корень на гласную не заканчивается.*

Согласен, слово для школы сложное, оно восходит к историческому корню *"чет"* *(чётный)*, ***"сочетать"***, таким образом, означает *делать что-то четным, парным*. И это значение частично можно проследить и в современном слове - *бракосочетание*, например, позволяет проследить значение "делать пару".

Другое дело, что слово это, как и многие другие древние слова, претерпело процесс морфемного переразложения, то есть корень современным носителем иногда воспринимается как **"сочет"**, но вряд ли **"сочетА"**.

Составители же вашего варианта ЕГЭ - как я понимаю, одного из бесчисленных тестовых вариантов сомнительного происхождения, - видимо, не договорились с Тихоновым и решили оставить все как было столетия назад: корень "чет",  проверочное - чётный, чётки, "со" - приставка, "ан(и)" - суффикс (или два суффикса)

Как быть в подобном случае на реальном ЕГЭ - я не знаю. Может быть, наши преподаватели подскажут, но лучше бы все-таки таких сомнительных вопросов там не было...

(++) ====
Самое смешное то, что в интернете есть эти варианты вопросов, но ответы к ним явно не авторами даны. Бог знает, кто эти вопросы составлял - и кто на них давал ответы.

(+++)  ====
Не мог не задать свой вопрос, косвенно связанный с разбираемым
[Может ли просторечный или жаргонный вариант случить проверочнвым словом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463519)