# Может ли просторечный или жаргонный вариант служить проверочным словом?

Tags: орфография

Вопрос " [«Экономический, офицерский, сочетание». Все слова с безударной непроверяемой гласной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463517) " заставил меня отвлечься от дел личных и задать вопрос, интересный сообществу.

Собственно, этот вопрос связан с упомянутым очень косвенно, поэтому изложу суть.

Есть слово "сочетание". При этом, согласно Тихонову, слог "со-" является частью корня (по Тихонову "школьный" корень - *сочета*, что само по себе весьма спорно). Таким образом, гласная Е - безударная корневая, а  проверочные "чет", "счет" не проходят, поскольку не являются (по Тихонову) однокоренными. Можно сделать вывод, что Е - непроверяемая. Однако... У медиков в большом ходу понятие "сочЕтанная [травма]" - именно с таким ударением, которое не признается словарями нормативным. Самое смешное, что за пределами медицинской сферы слово-то это почти не встречается, тем более с правильным ударением - сочетАнный.

Итак, вопрос. ***Может ли профжаргонное слово "сочЕтанный" служить проверочным для слова "соч(е/и)тание"?!***

(+) ====

*А еще есть "Алкоголь" - проверочное для "(а/о)лкоголик". Вообще у медиков много чего есть...
У бухгалтеров - "крЕдит" (проверочное для "кр(е/и)дитование"), у математиков - "комплЕксный" (проверочное для "компл(е/и)кс"). Как много слов-то можно проверить неправильными ударениями.*

И, конечно же, ***"шОфер" - проверочное к ш(о/a)ферить***.

Comment: behemothus, ещё: заголовок.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, спасибо. Совсем плохой стал...

Comment: В самом начале не закавычен «вопрос».

Comment: @shampar не вижу, исправьте, я откачу если что.

Comment: Как умею... Простите.

Comment: Вот поэтому и не надо быть умнее движка. Я понял, о чем вы, но так работает автоматическая вставка ссылок. Лучше не связываться

Comment: А так ссылки нет. )))

Comment: Короче, сделал под ваши пожелания максимально возможное.  Без пробелов кавычки убивают ссылку.

Comment: Да на фиг эти кавычки, imho.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - как по мне, так я согласен. Но есть у нас тут любители все делать рл инструкции. Кавычки - ещё ладно, тут хоть есть мотивация, а проблем особых не добавляет: хочется кавычек - нехай будут. А вот дефис на тире заменять - вот чего не понимаю изначально. Тут же фокус в том, что сравнительная длина тире и дефиса нигде в нормирующих источниках не оговаривается. дефис, грубо говоря, отличается от тире не длиной, а тем, что вокруг тире есть пробелы. Зато головной боли при такой замене можно поиметь - мало не покажется. Во всяком случае так было лет десять назад...

Comment: Сейчас-то устройств и программ, которые злостно не желают понимать расширенный набор символов не так много и осталось, но сама перекодировка - вещь трудозатратная...

Comment: Я на тире исправляю, просто чтобы покрасивше смотрелось.)) А его действительно какие-то программы не понимают, поэтому вы всегда ставите дефис?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ну вот, а кто-то без кавычек жить не может. ))) Да исправляыйте, я не против, коли уж тут такой подход сложился... Я фанатизма не понимаю в этом вопросе.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой что до проблемы "тире-дефис", то я уже лет пятнадцать вне активного программирования, но в мои годы она стояла. Были проблемы с воспроизведением оцифрованных текстов, например. И в какой-то мере они остались - классическая оцифровка по-прежнему работает с минимальным набором символов. А TXT формат (который по умолчанию должные распознавать все текстовики) никаких тире не предусматривает. В результате при цепочке преобразований форматов на выходе имеем неопределенность.

Comment: Это, впрочем, проблема не только "тире-дефис", там ещё буква Ё есть...  А в билингвальных источниках еще и то, что разный смысл у подобных знаков. Другой вопрос, кто сейчас этим вообще (кроме программистов) занимается...  Все ж на всем готовеньком привыкли, "как красивше", а что за этим стоит - так то проблемы негров и индейцев, которые шерифа не интересуют... Вот как-то так... Впрочем, "среди здесь"   есть и активные программисты, может и прокомментируют современное состояние.

Comment: Да зря вы про фанатизм. ;) На тире я меняю далеко не всегда. Вот пробелы лишние больше не люблю. Ещё, кстати, не понял, зачем вы сделали несколько абзацев без двойных пробелов. То есть внешне получилось то же, что и без абзацев: точка, пробел и следующая фраза на той же строчке.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  *Да зря вы про фанатизм* - да я вообще не вас имел в виду. Ни сейчас, ни тогда, когда эту тему поднял.

Comment: *не понял, зачем вы сделали несколько абзацев без двойных пробелов* - а черт его знает. Я очень наспех писал, боялся,, что в другой раз не найду в себе силы... Чего-то намудрил. Исправил.